# Not able to locate an android element using appium with java and POM

Tags: appium

I am using following non working code:

```java
AndroidElement el5 = 
    //(AndroidElement) driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='mobile number' and @class = 'android.widget.EditText']");
    (AndroidElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.EditText' and @bounds='[322,769][1135,845]']"));
```

[Image showing layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRiRI.png)

Comment: Please write your question/code as a text here and don't provide links to pics somewhere else (that may also get broken over time).

Comment: Hi Rohit, welcome to SO. Please add the layout xml and the actual behaviour - otherwise it is impossible to help you. Also please read [**how to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**how to create a minimum, reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for better results when using the site. Good luck!